# Is there a way to get a type from a function that takes a string for an argument?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that takes a single string arg.

I think in my first post of this issue I was not clear enought.

The purpose of this question is to figure how how to get typing (autocomplete) support for such methods without using cast.

`doc = CreateScritpService("Calc")`

To get the type I use cast.

`doc = cast(SFDocuments.SF_Calc, CreateScritpService("Calc"))`

`bas = cast(SFScriptForge.SF_Basic, CreateScriptService("Basic"))`

I am the Author of [ScriptForge Typings](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python-types-scriptforge)

An I am looking for a way to automatically have `CreateScritpService` return the correct type based upon the string input arg.
Is this possible?

Comment: if statement? dictionary? there are lots of ways to conditionally return things based on string arguments :)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I am looking to get typing support in the IDE from PYI files.

Comment: Has Python typing suddenly become the fashionable thing to do? It seems like the number of questions has surged recently.

Comment: @Barmar I can say for myself that I have written typing's for thousands of classes which have benefited many projects. In my experience when dealing with a large API such as [LibreOffice API](https://api.libreoffice.org/) is much, much more difficult without typings.

Comment: I just think that today I've seen more typing questions than any other day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `overload` along with `Literal`, something like this:

```py
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def CreateScriptService(x: Literal["Calc"]) -> SFDocuments.SF_Calc:
    ...

@overload
def CreateScriptService(x: Literal["Basic"]) -> SFScriptForge.SF_Basic:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I took this approach. Seems to work. I had [Hundreds of lines](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python-types-scriptforge/blob/1dd4e919c3f493c82fcb1eff6e67ea7491fbbf56/scriptforge/__init__.pyi#L7898) to do but its working.